# Any option to hide (Adsense-ads) code in desktop or tablet...?

Tags: ads, desktop, adsense, tablet

Any option to hide **(Adsense-Ad)** code in *desktop* or *tablet*?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with [LazyHTML](https://github.com/Niresh12495/LazyHTML/). It is an opensource JavaScript library that Lazyload Ads.

In head add the following script.

```
   <script async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lazyhtml@1.0.0/dist/lazyhtml.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Wrap adsense code like the following sample

```
<div class="lazyhtml" data-lazyhtml data-matchmedia="only screen and (max-width: 1024px)">
<script type="text/lazyhtml">
  <!--
    AD SCRIPT HERE (including wrapping <script> tag)
  -->
</script>
```

This will only show ads to screen width less than 1024 pixels.